# GPUImageview disappear after capture it

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I try to capture `GPUImageView` by using this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html)

but after I capture it `GPUImageview` is disappear, but if it is `UIImageView` it just working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered you in [your cross-posted question on GitHub](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/821), but the reason for this is the line in the above-linked documentation which states:

> Note that, CALayer/-renderInContext: captures only your UIKit and
>   Quartz drawing. It does not capture OpenGL ES or video content.

GPUImageView presents its content using OpenGL ES, so you can't capture it using `-renderInContext:`. You'll either need to extract your filter's image and manually composite it with your underlying view, or perform the compositing within GPUImage itself using a blend filter.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I will follow your suggestion.